# Typescript types for 2 React props that are related?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have some React components that accept 2 props where one prop depends on the other. I want to write a helper function to return these 2 props, then spread them on the component. However, Typescript doesn't seem to be able to maintain the relationship between these 2 props when spreading them.

E.g. the components would have types that look like:

```
function Component<
  A,
  B extends (A extends 'foo' ? { foo: number } : { bar: number })
>(props: {
  a: A,
  b: B,
}) {}

<Component a="foo" b={{ foo: 1 }} /> // ok
<Component a="bar" b={{ foo: 1 }} /> // error
```

The helper function would look like:

```
function getProps() {
  return Math.random() > 0.5
    ? { a: 'foo', b: { foo: 1 } }
    : { a: 'bar', b: { bar: 1 } };
}
```

The return type would be:

```
{ a: 'foo', b: { foo: number, bar?: undefined } }
| { a: 'bar', b: { bar: number, foo?: undefined } }
```

If I try to do `<Component {...getProps()} />`, I'd get something like `Type of { foo: number, bar?: undefined } isn't assignable to { bar: number }`. Pretty sure it's because TS is treating the union as:

```
{
  a: 'foo' | 'bar',
  b: { foo: number, bar?: undefined } | { bar: number, foo?: undefined }
}
```

Is there an easy way to make this work? Sample [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAeAUIriCCAaTbAIUQFMAPKUsAEwGdEAKHMy6+xAcmDjk8QD8iAN7JeALkRgQAWwBGpAE6IAvokmi5AQ0WTp8paoCU6AHyMADorgW6Gwli2T8DxHMlECKoyJXp0EAh0UIhWNgwAvIgAslpQABYAdIpatHAyjD6miAAMiQCsrkKiTlw8fIhaDIFgwXhuGmJwkgCMqqqujaWc2or8VYg1dQ0ibjqt7SoA3P4olta2RjNAA) using plain objects instead of React

Answer (score 0):

You can use a type assertion to explicitly the relation between the two props. I modified a little bit

```
type Props<T extends 'foo' | 'bar'> =
  T extends 'foo' ? { a: T, b: { foo: number } } :
  T extends 'bar' ? { a: T, b: { bar: number } } :
  never;

function getProps<T extends 'foo' | 'bar'>(a: T): Props<T> {
  if (a === 'foo') {
    return { a, b: { foo: 1 } } as Props<T>;
  } else {
    return { a, b: { bar: 1 } } as Props<T>;
  }
}
```

Then using like this

```
const props = getProps('foo');
<Component {...props} />;
```

I haven't faced this kind of issue before so not sure it works like you desire or not but take a try.